# (PHP) Unzip function fail to extract

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I use PHP zip function to extract files from a zip file

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;    
if($zip -> open ($filezip) === TRUE ) {
    $mani = $zip -> getFromName('MANIFEST.MF');
    echo $mani;
}
```

This script will extract the file MANIFEST.MF, but i have a problem, that if i rename this file to MANIFEST.Mf or mANIFEST.MF (with lowercase) from the zip file, it couldn't be extracted
Please help me to fix this code.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/ZipArchive) treats filenames from the archive case-sensitive, as do most Unix `zip` utilities. So does [`->getFromName()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getfromname.php)

You can only influence that behaviour for [`->locateName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.locatename.php) with the `ZIPARCHIVE::FL_NOCASE` flag.

```
echo
   $zip->getFromIndex(
      $zip->locateName('maNIFest.mF', ZIPARCHIVE::FL_NOCASE);
   );
```